# Cannot fill 100% height with flexbox, LESS, CSS on IE10

Tags: html, css, less, height, internet-explorer-10

Please help me, I cannot use the **100% of height** on my container on IE10, in Chrome and Firefox is easy, any idea?. Thanks!.

[you can see/edit on codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNBaJp)

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  position:relative;
  
}
.header, .footer{
  -ms-flex-negative:0;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: pink;
}

.x1 {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  background: cyan;
}
.x2 {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  header
</div>
<div class="container">
  container cannot fill 100% height on IE10
  <div class="x1">x1</div>
  <div class="x2">x2</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

Comment: didn't getting any issue.

Comment: on IE10 this cannot fill the 100% height of space available of the parent, cannot fill the space of the <body>

Comment: Ok i have IE9 so i cannot check. sorry. But IE 9 doesn't have an issue.